# Приоритет операций при поиске по меткам

Tags: поддержка, поиск

Хочу сделать сложный поиск. Например, есть метки: `[метка1]`, `[метка2]`, `[метка3]` - "хорошие", `[метка9]` - "плохая". Надо найти все вопросы, у которых есть хотя бы одна "хорошая", но исключить из выборки все вопросы с "плохой" меткой.  Получилось что-то вроде такого:

```
[метка1] -[метка9] or [метка2] -[метка9] or [метка3] -[метка9]
```

Результат выглядит более-менее как нужно, но этот момент в справке не освещен, так что хотелось бы подтверждения, что я угадал. И связанный вопрос - если плохих меток будет несколько? Каждую повторять по три раза?

Comment: О! А я вообще про `or` не знал... Точно работает?

Comment: Скобки не прокатывают?

Comment: `or` даже в справке есть. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching, в самом низу. Скобки пробовал, не работает вроде.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Better support for search by both intersection and union of multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231693/137096)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Должно быть достаточно написать так:

```
( [хорошая1] or [хорошая2] or [хорошая3] ) -[плохая1]
```

Если плохих несколько, то просто добавить их с минусом:

```
( [хорошая1] or [хорошая2] or [хорошая3] ) -[плохая1] -[плохая2] -[плохая3]
```

Comment: Не работает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+or+postgresql+-sql "Хорошие" - оракл и постгрес, "плохая" - sql. Попадается постгрес без sql, а оракл идет весь, и с sql, и без.

Comment: @Dmitry любопытно. Я проверял добавляя `is:q`, чтобы видеть метки у каждой записи (ибо только вопросы). Похоже на какой-то баг. Тогда могу предложить ещё добавить скобок.

Comment: Со скобками вообще мрак: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%5Boracle%5D+or+%5Bpostgresql%5D%29+-%5Bsql%5D А вот если добавить `is:q`, то работает. Наверно и правда баг.

Comment: @Dmitry со скобками надо пробелы добавлять, как у меня в ответе.

Comment: В любом случае, со скобками получается другой вид, где и ответы и вопросы. И надо `is:q` добавлять, чтобы только вопросы оставить.

Comment: @Dmitry так если нужны **только** вопросы, без `is:q` не обойтись в любом случае.

Comment: Нет, если вы введете `[oracle] or [postgresql] -[sql]` в поисковую строку, вы получите только вопросы.

Comment: @Dmitry точно. Это из-за разных способов отображения результатов поисковых запросов. Если в запросе только метки (и может быть всякие `or`, `-`...), то выводятся только вопросы на странице `/questions/tagged/`, а если добавить что-то ещё, то будет отображаться страница поиска `/search/`, где по умолчанию выводятся и вопросы, и ответы.

Comment: А можно ли искать так: (2 хорошие метки) или (2 другие хорошие метки) не [плохая метка]?

Comment: @NewPythonProgrammist попробуйте

Comment: @alexolut Пробовал. Не выходит. Есть ли способы это реализовать?

Comment: @NewPythonProgrammist опишите более подробно, что хочется сделать, и лучше, в составе нового вопроса на Мете, а не внутри комментариев.